# How to add data to BoxPlot in WFA?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, boxplot

I'm creating manually a boxplot chart. I have 4 double[] arrays with some calculations results that i want show on chart. I don't know how to connect correctly my arrays with chart Series.
Here is my chart:

```
        Chart chart = new Chart();
        chart.Series.Add("S1");
        chart.Series.Add("S2");
        chart.Series.Add("S3");
        chart.Series.Add("S4");
        chart.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1");
        chart.ChartAreas[0].Visible = true;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].Position.Auto = true;
        chart.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;
        chart.Series[1].ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;
        chart.Series[2].ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;
        chart.Series[3].ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;

        chart.Parent = this;
        chart.Visible = true;
        double[] yValues = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 2, 1, 9, 20, 4 };//example values
        chart.Series["S1"].Points.DataBindY(yValues);
```

This is what i get:

[image: my failed boxplot]

As result i want get something like that: [image: example boxplot]

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Comment: Yes, Your anserw solved my problem. Regular data binding was that what i need. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have tried to bind your data to a `BoxPlot` series. But this has only resulted in binding the first Y-value, which means you have created a set of 'lower whiskers'. All other 5 Y-values are empty, ie are `0`. Hence the meager graphics you see..

> [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456709.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):  The values for a box are typically calculated values from
>   data that is present in another series. One box symbol (DataPoint
>   object) is associated with one data series.
>
> The data for a Box Plot series may still be populated using
>   data binding, **or** by employing the Series.Points member (a
>   DataPointCollection object).

Let's look at all of these options:

1. Use regular data binding. This is what you tried but with a wrong syntax.
2. You can also add the `DataPoints` of the box plot series itself one by one with `AddY` or `AddXY`, **supplying all 6 Y-Values**, i.e. feeding in the results of a statistical analysis. Here only one array is used and it contains the six y-values.
3. Or you can use one or more data series and let the chart summarize those data in one box per series. The series are quite normal, read may be `Point`, `Line` or whatever.. They can even be invisible and of course you can use data binding for them.. - Once some data series are in place you can define the `BoxPlot` series and 'bind' it to the data series by seting its `["BoxPlotSeries"]` special property to a string into which you concatenate the Series' Names...

**Option 1. Use regular data binding to feed in the stats you have.**

This is what you tried. The correct way is a little surprising, though; your data need to be ordered like this:

The outer array (or `IEnumerable`) must have the six y-values; the six inner arrays should contain one value for each of the data sets you want to show in a box. Let's look at an example with three data sets of faked stats:

```
double[][] yValues = {
            new[]{ 15.6, 24.4, 36.1 },  // Lower whiskers
            new[]{ 46.2, 52.2, 91.9 },  // Upper whiskers
            new[]{ 22.3, 27.2, 55.9 },  // Lower boxes
            new[]{ 33.2, 44.4, 77.9 },  // Upper boxes
            new[]{ 25.2, 38.4, 68.5 },  // Averages and means
            new[]{ 27.4, 32.4, 66.9 }   // Medians
        };
```

This is how it looks after binding it to a `BoxPlot` series `S1`

```
S1.Points.DataBindY(yValues);
```

[image]

You can also create individual series; see the update at the bottom for this!

**Option 2: Feed in the `BoxPlot` data yourself**

Let's look at an example of the first way: Here **we** need to have the statistics ready.. First I create a random data structure; it is a `List` of `double arrays` each with 6 elements:

```
Random R = new Random(23);
List<double[]> yValues = new List<double[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    { R.Next(5),      R.Next(5) + 20, R.Next(5) + 3, 
      R.Next(5) + 10, R.Next(5) +  5, R.Next(5) + 7 });
}
```

Now we add those fake statistics to the `BoxPlot` series:

```
S1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;
S1.Points.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < yValues.Count; i++ ) S1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(i, yValues[i]));
```

Note that each `DataPoint` is created from an array of 6 doubles!

Here is the result:

[image]

The chart now shows stats on 8 data sets, all faked ;-)

**Option 3a: Associate some data series with the `BoxPlot` and let it do the math**

The other usage is to **let the chart to the math**: It can calculate the statistics for any number of data series you have and create **one** box for each.

We will use the same data set as before, but now they are used to create 6 data series, each with 8 points:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    Series ds = chart.Series.Add("D" + (i+1));  // set a name D1, D2..
    dx.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    dx.Points.DataBindY(yValues.Select(x => x[i]).ToArray());
}
```

They are bound to the same numbers as above, but these now have a different meaning. Therefore the results will and should **not** look alike!!

In fact you can look at the boxes and graphs and see how they nicely fit.

Note the `Names` I gave the data series; we will need them now, when we 'bind' them to the `BoxPlot` series:

```
S1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;
S1["BoxPlotSeries"] = "D1;D2;D3;D4;D5;D6";  // box plot binding!
S1.LegendText = "BoxPlot";
```

[image]

I use quotes for the 'binding' because it isn't **real** data binding; instead the data series are only **associated** with the `BoxPlot` series with the sprecial property string `"BoxPlotSeries"`.

Your example has more than one `BoxPlot` series; here the same rules apply.

Do have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268436/how-to-create-box-plot-for-a-series-of-data-without-x-values) which shows another use of `BoxPlot` including setting individual colors..

**Option 3b: Associate some data series with DataPoints you add to the `BoxPlot` series; here too it will do the math for us**

While option 3a seems rather simple I found no way to color the boxes. Here is how we can do that:

First we force the chart to copy the default colors to the series. While we're at it, let's also hide the `Legend` item:

```
S1.Color = Color.Transparent;
S1.LegendText = " ";
chart.ApplyPaletteColors()
```

Then we create one `DataPoint` in out `BoxPlot` series `S1` for each data series; not how my series are ordered: *0=The BoxPlot, 1-6 some data series*! You may need to adapt this!

```
for (int i = 1; i < chart.Series.Count; i++)
{
    DataPoint dp = new DataPoint();
    S1.Points.Add(dp);
    dp["BoxPlotSeries"] =  "D" + i;  // names D1-D6
    dp.Color = chart.Series[i].Color;
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

**Update:**

Your example actually shows three boxplot series; hence the colors and most notably: the clustered (i.e. gapless) display.

This would be a way to bind the above data (from option 1) to three individual boxes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    Series bps = chart.Series.Add("BoxPlotSeries" + i);
    bps.ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;
    var yValOne = yValues.Select(x => new[] { x[i] }).ToArray();
    bps.Points.DataBindY(yValOne);
}
```

[image]

**Final note**: Your example code contains an array with 12 doubles and also 4 boxplot series. This makes no sense. You can add the 12 values to a normal series and associate it with one boxplot series using option 3, though..